# Photoshop Actions: Export with exact pixel size, not percentage

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, export, actions

When I record actions, I put in the pixel size I want it to save as (1000x1000) for web export. For some reason, it will only replay this action and resize based on a scaling percentage. Is there a way to fix this without having to edit scripts? I tried changing preferences for units to pixels, but that didn't work. Please help!

Comment: Can you give us a rundown of what the action is doing? There’s probably a few ways to solve it, but it’ll depend on your exact steps and desired outcome.

Answer (score 2):

When you record your action, before exporting click Image > Duplicate. Rescale the duplicate using Image > Image Size. Export the duplicate using File > Export > Save for Web (Legacy). Then close the duplicate without saving it.

This allows you to basically create a temporary document for rescaling purposes, without affecting the original image.

Answer (score 0):

Record with "Image Size" function used.
After recording the action, in action panel,
click "Action 1" -> Image Size(Double Click) -> set pixel or percentage or ...
then run again

Comment: Do you mean to just add a new action where I resize the image? The thing is, I don't want to change the size of the original image. I only want it to export as a different size, then the action list will save the original image in psd format.

Comment: Also, there's no listing for "Image Size" within my action. It only says has horizontal and vertical scaling.

Comment: If you want to preserve the size of the image, record a final step in the action that reverts back to the original document state in the history panel (after exporting at 1000 x 1000).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this can be done using "Save for web ... " in an action. However, Minu J is correct - you can use Image Size (under the Image menu) for this:

[image]